# Removing Dupes while parsing/scraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, duplicates

I have read and did some research, I can get duplicates removed while loading a list from file dialog, but how do you auto remove dupes while scraping/parsing. Below is my code and the hash tags are some of the dict and list functions I have tried.Thanks for the help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
import itertools
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# URL LIST:
url = [
'URL0',
'URL1',
]
#OPTIONS/REQUESTS:
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')
#options.add_argument("--headerless")
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'

requests = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
requests.implicitly_wait(10)
wait = WebDriverWait(requests, 10)

#USE SPIKE = [] FOR APPEND
#spike = []
#spike: list[str, int, set] = []
#ele: dict[set] = {}
spike: dict[set] = []
#REQUESTS/SLEEP FOR LOOP:

for url in url:

    #ele = ele.text    
    requests.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)


#FOR ELEMENTS WITHIN XPATH:

    try:
        for ele in requests.find_elements(By.XPATH, '(//pre["text()"])[position() < 10]'):
            try:
                spike.append(ele.text.splitlines(keepends=False))
                time.sleep(5)
                for i in range(len(spike)):
                    print('\n'.join(spike[i]))
            except:
                requests.close()
            
        else:
            requests.get(url)
    except:
        requests.close()
else:
    requests.quit()
#SAVE ELEMENTS WITHIN XPATH:
    with open("text.txt", "wt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            for i in range(len(spike)):
                print("\n".join(spike[i]), file=file)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just adding this code to the GUI I've been working on and used the following to remove duplicates:

```
def contain(key):
    item = key in listbox.get(0, END)
    return item


for key in spike[i]:
    if contain(key) == True:
        pass
    else:
        listbox.insert(END,key)
```